# Flatten once procedure

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I'm having a bit of a struggle with coding a procedure that flattens a list once, i.e 
`(flatten-once '((b) (c f) ((d)(e))))` would produce `'(b c f (d) (e)))`. I checked up on a few sources on how the standard flatten procedure works but it implements functions that are not included in the `intermediate student with lambda` language form I'm required to use. As far as I have it figured out a `foldr` would be somewhat helpful and have managed to get this

```
(define (flatten-once lst)
  (cond
   [(empty? lst) lst]
   [else 
    ((foldr cons (first (rest lst)) (first lst)))]))
```

which returns `'(b c f)` , so I guess it flattens part of the list. I tried continuing the definition through recursion but that just gives errors, so I guess I'm missing something.

Comment: Although it's N/A for your school assignment and Intermediate Student Language, in "real" Racket "flatten one level" is [`append*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._append%2A%29%29).

Answer (score 7):

The proposed code is overly complicated, resist the temptation to use folds everywhere, they're not the answer to everything  - I say this because I've seen other of your questions and frequently, there's an unnecessary call to `foldr` or `foldl`. A simple `append` will do the trick:

```
(define (flatten-once lst)
  (apply append lst))
```

It works as expected:

```
(flatten-once '((b) (c f) ((d)(e))))
=> '(b c f (d) (e))
```

If the input list contains elements which are not lists, then a bit more of work needs to be done. To be extra-careful, we can do this:

```
(define (flatten-once lst)
  (apply append
         (map (lambda (e) (if (cons? e) e (list e)))
              lst)))
```

Now it'll work for inputs such as this one, noticing that the element `a` was added to the list. Another alternative would be to *delete it* from the list, if that makes more sense then replace `(list e)` with `'()` in the code above.

```
(flatten-once '(a (b) (c f) ((d)(e))))
=> '(a b c f (d) (e))
```

Finally, in the spirit of @Alex's answer, this second variant can also be written using `foldr`:

```
(define (flatten-once lst)
  (foldr (lambda (e acc)
           (append (if (cons? e) e (list e)) acc))
         '()
         lst))
```

Comment: What about `(flatten-once '(a (b) (c f) ((d)(e))))` ?

Comment: @uselpa it's unknown if the input can contain non-lists, but to play it safe, I updated my answer. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: `pair?` isn't defined in `Intermediate student with lambda`

Comment: No need to copy `(list e)` with `append`;  The folding function could equivalently be `(lambda (e acc) (if (cons? e) (append e acc) (cons e acc)))`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor no need. you can't append a non-list, so it should just fail if non-lists are present, IMHO.

Comment: @WillNess But answer already has code `(append (if … … (list e)) acc)`.  I was just pointing out that it could be instead `(if … (append … acc) (cons e acc))`, which avoids a bunch of memory allocation.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor it was a generic "you", in "you can't append a non-list". :) It could've been "one" as well, as in "one can't ...". Just a figure of speech :) making a side remark. (plus, having two '@'s in comment doesn't work).

Answer (score 2):

The trick is as Óscar López already said, to use `append`.

If you want to use a solution with `foldr` :

```
(define (flatten-once lst)
  (foldr append '() lst))
```

It should work as expected.

Comment: What about `(flatten-once '(a (b) (c f) ((d)(e))))` ?

Comment: @uselpa Another place where'd it'd be nice if Scheme/Racket's `fold[lr]` functions took a `key` argument like Common Lisp's `reduce` does;  it'd be `(reduce 'append lst :key 'to-list)`. :\

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor What is `to-list`?

Comment: @uselpa It's that utility function that you'd have defined earlier. :)  `(defun to-list (x) (if (listp x) x (list x)))`, or `(define (to-list x) (if (list? x) x (list x)))`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor OK, mine was `(defun to-list (e) (if (atom e) (list e) e))
`. But `(reduce 'append (mapcar 'to-list lst))` would also do, right?

Comment: It's worth noting here that it's important that you're using the _right_ associative fold.  For a list `(w x y z)`, it's equivalent to `(append w (append x (append y (append z '()))))`, which copies just enough (the length of the result) and should run in linear time.  A _left_ associative fold would be `(append (append (append (append w '()) x) y) z)` and would allocate lots of extra memory, and would run in quadratic time.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor If you're concerned about speed, avoid `append`.

Comment: @uselpa Is there a faster way than `append` to take two lists `x` and `y` and make a new list that begins with the elements of `x` and has `y` as a tail?  Unless the OP wants to do this destructively, all of those next-to-top level lists need to be copied (except the last), and that's just what `append` does.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor In Racket, according to my tests, my solution is the fastest.

Comment: @uselpa I believe it should fail because you can not append a non-list.

Comment: @WillNess Not sure if I get you, can you give an example?

Comment: @uselpa _your_ example, in the 1st comment here.

Comment: @WillNess Sure, you are right, that was my point. But all examples of flatten I have seen until now were able to deal with that, hence my comment.

Comment: @uselpa yes, this is of course entirely a matter of taste. :)

Answer (score 1):

Less elegant that Oscar's version, but without `append` (and twice as fast in my tests):

```
(define (flatten-once lst)
  (reverse
   (let loop ((lst lst) (first #t) (res null))
     (if (null? lst)
         res
         (let ((e (car lst)))
           (loop (cdr lst) 
                 first
                 (if (and first (cons? e))
                     (loop e #f res)
                     (cons e res))))))))
```

NB in `intermediate student with lambda language` this needs to be expressed as:

```
(define (flatten-once-helper lst first res)
  (if (null? lst)
      res
      (let ((e (car lst)))
        (flatten-once-helper 
         (cdr lst) 
         first
         (if (and first (cons? e))
             (flatten-once-helper e #f res)
             (cons e res))))))

(define (flatten-once lst)  
  (reverse (flatten-once-helper lst #t null)))
```

Comment: In my earlier comments on another answer (e.g., "what would do this faster than `append`?") I'd just been looking at that answer, and hadn't looked at yours yet. I can see why yours would be faster;  it's an implementation of `(append list1 list2 ... tail)`, but without the non-optimizable function call overhead (that would happen with `(foldr append ...)`, both from the `foldr`, but also the calls to `append`.  This is some pretty aggressive unrolling optimization!