# Creating repetitions of list with mapcan freezes?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have two lists: `(1 2 3)` and `(a b)` and I need to create something like this `(1 2 3 1 2 3)`.  The result is a concatenation of the first list as many times as there are elements in the second. I should use some of the functions (`maplist`/`mapcar`/`mapcon`, etc.). This is exactly what I need, although I need to pass first list as argument:

```
(mapcan #'(lambda (x) (list 1 2 3)) (list 'a 'b))
;=> (1 2 3 1 2 3)
```

When I try to abstract it into a function, though, Allegro freezes:

```
(defun foo (a b)
  (mapcan #'(lambda (x) a) b))

(foo (list 1 2 3) (list 'a 'b))
; <freeze>
```

Why doesn't this definition work?

Comment: So, what's the specification? "Given lists `a` and `b`, construct a new list `c` such, that it is a concatenation of `a` with itself; the number of repetitions of elements of `a` in `c` is the length of `b`". Is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could

```
(defun f (lst1 lst2)
  (reduce #'append (mapcar (lambda (e) lst1) lst2)))
```

then

```
? (f '(1 2 3) '(a b))
(1 2 3 1 2 3)
```

Comment: You should be careful with `(reduce 'append ...)` though, since makes lots and lots of copies of the lists.  E.g., see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147865/flatten-once-procedure#comment30042917_20148465). (You were actually involved in that thread, too.)  As such, this should really be `(reduce 'append ... :from-end t)`.

Answer (score 4):

There's already an accepted answer, but I think some more explanation about what's going wrong in the original code is in order.  `mapcan` applies a function to each element of a list to generate a bunch of lists which are destructively concatenated together.  If you destructively concatenate a list with itself, you get a circular list.  E.g.,

```
(let ((x (list 1 2 3)))
  (nconc x x))
;=> (1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 ...)
```

Now, if you have more concatenations than one, you can't finish, because to concatenate something to the end of a list requires walking to the end of the list.  So

```
(let ((x (list 1 2 3)))
  (nconc (nconc x x) x))
;        -----------      (a)
; ---------------------   (b)
```

(a) terminates, and returns the list `(1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 ...)`, but (b) can't terminate since we can't get to the end of `(1 2 3 1 2 3 ...)` in order to add things to the end.

Now  that leaves the question of why

```
(defun foo (a b)
  (mapcan #'(lambda (x) a) b))

(foo (list 1 2 3) '(a b))
```

leads to a freeze.  Since there are only two elements in `(a b)`, this amounts to:

```
(let ((x (list 1 2 3)))
  (nconc x x))
```

That should terminate and return an infinite list `(1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 ...)`.  In fact, it does.  The problem is that *printing* that list in the REPL will hang.  For instance, in SBCL:

```
CL-USER> (let ((x (list 1 2 3)))
           (nconc x x))
; <I manually stopped this, because it hung.

CL-USER> (let ((x (list 1 2 3)))
           (nconc x x)            ; terminates
           nil)                   ; return nil, which is easy to print
NIL
```

If you set `*print-circle*` to true, you can see the result from the first form, though:

```
CL-USER> (setf *print-circle* t)
T
CL-USER> (let ((x (list 1 2 3)))
           (nconc x x))
#1=(1 2 3 . #1#)                  ; special notation for reading and
                                  ; writing circular structures
```

The *simplest* way (i.e., fewest number of changes) to adjust your code to remove the problematic behavior is to use `copy-list` in the lambda function:

```
(defun foo (a b)
  (mapcan #'(lambda (x)
              (copy-list a))
          b))
```

This also has an advantage over a `(reduce 'append (mapcar ...) :from-end t)` solution in that it doesn't necessarily allocate an intermediate list of results.

Comment: I ran both functions: `(defun foo1 (a b) (reduce #'append (mapcar (lambda (x) a) b) :from-end t))` and `(defun foo2 (a b) (mapcan #'(lambda (x) (copy-list a)) b))` with `(time (foo1 '(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p r s t u v w x y z) '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)))` and the result was: foo1: 245 cons cells, foo2: 251 cons cells. Doesn't that mean foo1 is more effective?

Comment: @chriemmy the `mapcan/copy-list` solution produces one more copy of the first list than `reduce/append/mapcar` (since `append` doesn't copy its tail).  However, the `mapcan/copy-list` doesn't store an intermediate list of results that's the length of the second list.  Try the same test with a first list that's longer than the second (e.g., swap `(0 ... 9)` and `(a ... z)`).  That difference doesn't matter so much, but both are **much** better than `reduce/.../:from-end nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb is to make sure the function supplied to `mapcan` (and destructive friends) creates the list or else you'll make a loop. The same applies to arguments supplied to other destructive functions. Usually it's best if the function has made them which makes it only a linear update.

This will work:

```
(defun foo (a b)
  (mapcan #'(lambda (x) (copy-list a)) b))
```

Here is some alternatives:

```
(defun foo (a b)
  ;; NB! apply sets restrictions on the length of b. Stack might blow
  (apply #'append (mapcar #'(lambda (x) a) b)) 

(defun foo (a b)
   ;; uses loop macro
   (loop for i in b
         append a))
```

I really don't understand why b cannot be a number? You're really using it as church numbers so I think I would have done this instead:

```
(defun x (list multiplier)
   ;; uses loop
   (loop for i from 1 to multiplier
         append list))

(x '(a b c) 0) ; ==> nil
(x '(a b c) 1) ; ==> (a b c)
(x '(a b c) 2) ; ==> (a b c a b c)

;; you can still do the same:
(x '(1 2 3) (length '(a b))) ; ==> (1 2 3 1 2 3)
```